# MySql "sending data" process is too long

Tags: mysql, performance, server, debian, mariadb

I think my probleme comes for hardware, let me explain. I have a web server 64GB RAM 16 processors. 
In this web server I have a KVM, 16GB RAM 8 processors. I have in the both servers (kvm and physical) the same version and configuration for apache2 and mariadb. Same databse structure, indexes, data, etc

My probleme appears with the KVM. I have a php script, who execute MySql queries, and sometimes a query take a lot of time with sending data process (more than 60s sometimes to return 30 results, and sometimes more than 200s!), and sometimes the query is execute in less than 1s. I don't understand why...

Ps: on my physical web server I have no problems, all my queries are execute less than 1s.

I have a read somewhere perhaps the probleme comes for i/o disk access is it possible ?

Comment: I found the solution, I edited `my.cnf` and I added these lines  `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 12G
innodb_log_buffer_size         = 8M                                  innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
innodb_log_file_size           = 256M
innodb_flush_method            = O_DIRECT`  with this all my queries are execute less than 1s

Comment: Even 1s is too slow in my book.  And the improvement you quote implies that it was touching a lot of rows, thereby I/O-bound.  Sometimes performance can be improved by adding a composite index or reformulating a query.  Let's see one of those 60s queries, plus its `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`  Maybe we can speed it up even more.